# Reference parent token of a content-type X via content-type Z to generate URL alias?

Tags: entities, path-aliases

I have three content types (X, Y, Z) and each have an Entity Reference field.

- Content-type X has an Entity Reference field to a Taxonomy vocabulary with two terms, A and B. Term A has a child, 1.
- Content-type Y has an Entity Reference field to X.
- Content-type Z has an Entity Reference field to Y.

By using Pathauto and enabling Entity tokens, I'm able to generate some nice URLs for these content-types:

Content-type X
example/vocabulary-parent(if present)/vocabulary-term-child/content-type-x-year

Content-type Y
example/vocabulary-parent(if present)/vocabulary-term-child/content-type-x-year/content-type-y-name

But, I run into an issue when I'm trying to create a URL with content-type Z. The token for child 1's parent (Term A) is not present -- or at least I can't seem to find it. The Pathauto pattern below only generates the child's name:

example/[node:field-content-type-z:field-content-type-y:field-content-type-x]

However, the token to access child 1's parent is present when generating content-type Y:

example/[node:field-content-type-y:field-content-type-x:**parent**]

Is there a way to generate a URL alias that includes child 1's parent name for content-type Z?

Comment: I found the answer on a previous thread's comment http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/88566/49970